# Shuffle the records of a list of text files in one single file

Tags: python, algorithm, file

I have a list of text files `file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt .. filen.txt` that I need to shuffle creating one single big file as result <sup>*</sup>.

*Requirements*:
   1. The records of a given file need to be reversed before being shuffled
   2. The records of a given file should keep the reversed order in the destination file
   3. I don't know how many files I need to shuffle so the code should be generic as possible (allowing to declare the file names in a list for example)
   4. Files could have different sizes

Example:

> ```
> File1.txt
> ---------
> File1Record1
> File1Record2
> File1Record3
> File1Record4
>
> File2.txt
> ---------
> File2Record1
> File2Record2
>
>
> File3.txt
> ---------
> File3Record1
> File3Record2
> File3Record3
> File3Record4
> File3Record5
> ```

the output should be something like this:

> ```
> ResultFile.txt
> --------------
> File3Record5   -|
> File2Record2    |
> File1Record4    |
> File3Record4   -|
> File2Record1    |
> File1Record3    |-->File3 records are shuffled with the other records and 
> File3Record3   -|   are correctly "reversed" and they kept the correct 
> File1Record2    |   ordering
> File3Record2   -|
> File1Record1    |
> File3Record1   -|
> ```

<sup>* I'm not crazy; I have to import these files (blog posts) using the resultfile.txt as input</sup>

**EDIT:**
the result could have any sort you want, completely or partially shuffled, uniformly interleaved, it does not matter. What it does matter is that points 1. and 2. are both honoured.

Comment: Do we assume that all of the contents would fit into memory or should intermediate files be used? Because of reversing I think it cannot be done 'in place'.

Comment: @Paj good question; memory should not be a problem on my beefed machine.

Comment: Do you mean *shuffled* or *mixed* respectively *zipped*?

Comment: @Oben it does not matter, the most important thing is that points 1. and 2. are both honoured.

Comment: Why do you need to shuffle them at all? Why not just list the reversed content of each file in order?

Comment: @Karl, @systempuntoout, I was thinking about asking the same thing.

Comment: @Karl because I have to interleave the records a little bit.

Comment: What Bad Thing(TM) happens if they aren't interleaved?

Comment: @Karl one reason is because I have to import different categories of blog posts from different files and I would like to shuffle them a little to avoid to have all the posts of the same category on the front page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
>>> l = [["1a","1b","1c","1d"], ["2a","2b"], ["3a","3b","3c","3d","3e"]]
>>> while l:
...     x = random.choice(l)
...     print x.pop(-1) 
...     if not x:
...         l.remove(x)

1d
1c
2b
3e
2a
3d
1b
3c
3b
3a
1a
```

You could optimize it in various ways, but that's the general idea. This also works if you cannot read the files at once but need to iterate them because of memory restrictions. In that case

- read a line from the file instead of popping from a list
- check for EOF instead of empty lists

Comment: I don't think he meant 'shuffle' but more like mix together. But I'm not completely shure :)

Comment: +1, we did practically the same thing at the same time. (But I forgot about `random.choice` -- whoops!)

Comment: @senderley: Yes, and @pajton also did the same. Actually we should merge our answers and share reps :)

Answer (score 2):

you could try the following: in a first step you `zip()` the `reversed()` items of the list:

```
zipped = zip(reversed(lines1), reversed(lines2), reversed(lines3))
```

then you can concatenate the items in zipped again:

```
lst = []
for triple in zipped:
    lst.append(triple)
```

finally you have to remove all `None`s added by `zip()`

```
lst.remove(None)
```

Comment: I was about to post the same. +1 ! ;)

Comment: Look at his example. The lists are not 'shuffled' but mixed together. I guess he used a wrong description. But I am not entirely sure.

Comment: @Constantinius, they aren't completely "shuffled" but they are also not uniformly interleaved, unlike the results from `zip`. Also -- what `None`s? `>>> zip([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])`: `[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]`.

Comment: @Const sorry but, what's the difference between shuffled and mixed together? I have to shuffle the record from different files keeping the original order (but reversed) for any given files. Is 'mixed together' more clear?

Comment: The question is if you explicitly want some randomness in the order of your records, or if you just want to mix them.

Comment: I guess so. Maybe you should state this in your question.

Comment: @senderle: you are right I have to improve my solution a bit.

Comment: @Oben some randomness is well accepted but it is not explicitly required.

Comment: @Constantinius, looking again at the output, I realize that they are interleaved after all. I was reading from the bottom :). Sorry about that. For the `None` problem, may I suggest `itertools.izip_longest`?

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution might be to create a list of lists, and then pop a line off a random list until they're all exhausted:

```
>>> import random
>>> filerecords = [['File{0}Record{1}'.format(i, j) for j in range(5)] for i in range(5)]
>>> concatenation = []
>>> while any(filerecords):
...     selection = random.choice(filerecords)
...     if selection:
...         concatenation.append(selection.pop())
...     else:
...         filerecords.remove(selection)
... 
>>> concatenation
['File1Record4', 'File3Record4', 'File0Record4', 'File0Record3', 'File0Record2',
 'File4Record4', 'File0Record1', 'File3Record3', 'File4Record3', 'File0Record0',
 'File4Record2', 'File2Record4', 'File4Record1', 'File3Record2', 'File4Record0',
 'File2Record3', 'File1Record3', 'File2Record2', 'File2Record1', 'File3Record1',
 'File3Record0', 'File1Record2', 'File2Record0', 'File1Record1', 'File1Record0']
```

Comment: You could implement a weighted selection algorithm if you wanted a distribution in which shorter lists are selected less often.

Answer (score 2):

```
filenames = [ 'filename0', ... , 'filenameN' ]
files = [ open(fn, 'r') for fn in filenames ]
lines = [ f.readlines() for f in files ]

output = open('output', 'w')

while len(lines) > 0:
    l = random.choice( lines )
    if len(l)==0: 
        lines.remove(l)
    else:
        output.write( l.pop() )

output.close()
```

One bite may seem magical here: the lines read from files don't need reversing, because when we write them to output file we use `list.pop()` which takes items from the end of the list (here the contents of the file).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend investing some time to read [*Generator Tricks for Systems Programmers*](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/Generators.pdf)(PDF). It's from a presentation at PyCon 08 and it deals specifically with processing arbitrarily large log files. The reversal aspect is an interesting wrinkle, but the rest of the presentation should speak directly to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
filelist = (
    'file1.txt',
    'file2.txt',
    'file3.txt',
)

all_records = []

max_records = 0
for f in filelist:
    fp = open(f, 'r')
    records = fp.readlines()
    if len(records) > max_records:
        max_records = len(records)
    records.reverse()
    all_records.append(records)
    fp.close()

all_records.reverse()

res_fp = open('result.txt', 'w')
for i in range(max_records):
    for records in all_records:
        try:
            res_fp.write(records[i])
        except IndexError:
            pass
    i += 1
res_fp.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a python zen master, but here's my take.

```
import random

#You have you read everything into a list from at least one of the files.
fin = open("filename1","r").readlines()
# tuple of all of the files.
fls = ( open("filename2","r"), 
       open("filename3","r"), )

for fl in fls: #iterate through tuple
   curr = 0
   clen = len(fin)
   for line in fl: #iterate through a file.
      # If we're at the end or 1 is randomly chosen, insert at current position.
      if curr > clen or round(random.random()):
         fin.insert(curr,line)
         clen = len(fin)
      curr +=1 #increment current index.

# when you're *done* reverse. It's easier.
fin.reverse()
```

Unfortunately with this it becomes obvious that this is a weighted distrobution. This can be fixed by calculating the length of each of the files and multiplying the call to random by certain probability based on that. I'll see if I can't provide that at some later point.

Answer (score 0):

A possible merging function is available in the standard library. It's intended to merge sorted lists to make sorted combined lists; garbage in, garbage out, but it does have the desired property of maintaining sublist order no matter what.

```
def merge_files(output, *inputs):
    # all parameters are opened files with appropriate modes.
    from heapq import merge
    for line in heapq.merge(*(reversed(tuple(input)) for input in inputs)):
        output.write(line)
```